# In javascript, is it possible to add a string to a function name?

Tags: javascript, function

I just wanted to ask if it is possible to take a string, which will always be constant and add a function's name to it.
an example:

```
function modifyFunctionName(theFunc)
{
    var newFunc = "link" +theFunc;
    return newFunc;
}
//Somewhere in the HTML:
<input type='submit' value='button' onclick='modifyFunctionName(CheckLogin())'/>
```

So the `modifyFunctionName` will return `linkCheckLogin()`.

EDIT: Sorry guys actually what I was exactly trying to do was this: https://gist.github.com/2371187

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for an XY Problem (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: It seems, that OP want's to assign a different event handler function to the `button`, depended on `CheckLogin()` return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It technically is possibly, but you would have to use `eval` and that isn't a good idea.  What you could do is create an object and just store references to functions and it would work about the same way.

```
var obj={};

function addFunction(name,func){
  obj[name]=func;
}

function changeName(oName,nName){
  obj[nName]=obj[oName];
  delete obj[oName];
}

addFunction('test',function(){return 'hi'});
obj.test();//returns 'hi'
changeName('test','greet');
obj.greet();//returns 'hi'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

    function one() {
        alert("one");
    }

    eval("function two() { one();}");
    two();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the question :
it is not very clear what you intend to do , anyway , you can eval anything that is attached to a scope :

```
myFunction(aString){
// window is the scope , the context.
window[aString] = myFunction ;
}
```

the question is why would you want to do that ?